# UIImageView does not display downloaded image in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that should display photos.

Everything works when I display a temp image from Assets.xcassets, but when I download the image from the Internet it does not display anything.

CollectionViewController.swift

```
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var currentCategory:PhotoCategory!

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return currentCategory.images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GalleryItemCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! GalleryItemCollectionViewCell

        cell.setGalleryItem(imageURL: currentCategory.images[indexPath.row].image)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let picDimension = self.view.frame.size.width / 4.0
        return CGSize(width: picDimension, height: picDimension)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        let leftRightInset = self.view.frame.size.width / 20.0
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftRightInset, 0, leftRightInset)
    }
}
```

GalleryItemCollectionViewCell.swift

```
class GalleryItemCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var itemImageView: UIImageView!

    func setGalleryItem(imageURL:String) {
        //itemImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tempImage2")
        let url = URL(string: imageURL)
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if let imageData = data {
                    if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                        print("We do have the image")
                        self.itemImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I do see "We do have the image" in the output, so the download is completed and the data is a UIImage.

If I uncomment the line:

```
//itemImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tempImage2")
```

and remove the following async, everything works.

When I use the download code in a ViewController to display a normal UiImageView it does work.

**Update:**

I ended up adding a extension to UIImageView to the project:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadedFrom(link:String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode) {
        guard
            let url = NSURL(string: link)
            else {return}
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.image = image
            });
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

and I add the pictures like this in cellForItemAt:

```
cell.itemImageView.downloadedFrom(link: cell.photo.image, contentMode: .scaleAspectFill)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                    print("We do have the image")
                    self.itemImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                }
```

change to

```
if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                    print("We do have the image")
                    self.itemImageView.image = image
                }
```